# git rm --cached results in fatal: pathspec

Tags: git

I wanted to clean my repo up after adding some files to `.gitignore` so I ran
`git rm --cached *` with the result:
`fatal: pathspec '$Recycle.Bin' did not match any files`

I assume this is due to the `$` in the filename, is there a work around for this?

Comment: If you run rm --cached "$Recycle.Bin", what happens?

Comment: The same error is what happens Lajos Arpad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just how `*` works.  It has nothing to do with the `$` at all.

```
$ ls
$Recycle.Bin
a
b
```

If I run `git rm --cached *`, the shell converts that to `git rm --cached $Recycle.bin a b`, and that's what's passed to Git.

However, `$Recycle.Bin` isn't part of your repository, so Git can't delete it.  That's an error.  Easiest way to fix this is to not use `--ignore-unmatch`.

```
$ git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch -- *
```

Comment: Perfect, just one change needed it be recursive, added a `-r` thanks!  `git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch -r -- *`

Answer (score 1):

The workaround is to replace '*' with more bounded wildcard/globs. For instance you could use something of the form mydir/{dir1,dir2}/*.{js,css}

Which should give you some idea of what you can do.

Then look at your changes to .gitignore and do a git rm --cached on each line entry, using wildcards to combine entries in case your gitignore is bloated